# Error whille installing flex in Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I type `sudo apt-get install flex` in the terminal in Ubuntu 10.4 LTS, the following message is displayed and the process terminates:

```
reading package lists...done

building dependency tree 

reading state information..done

package flex is not available ....but is referred to by another package

this may mean that package flex is missing, has been obsoleted or is only available from another source
E: package flex has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Did you install bison?  If so, what are the recommendations, and is flex one of them?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run `sudo apt-get update`? If you run that, and then run `sudo apt-get install flex` afterwards, does it work? If not, then please provide the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` (by editing your question to include it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your packages might not be up-to-date so just run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And after executing this command run your command again. This worked for me.